# How to rewrite return method at got.post() (using jest mock), so I can call json method

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I try using jest for test my script (typescript)

```
// api.ts
import got from "got";


export const run = async () => {
  const body = await got.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').json();
  return body;
};
```

and my test

```
// api.test.ts
import { run } from "../api";
import got from "got";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/dist/util/testing";

jest.mock("got");

test("using another got", async () => {
  const response = {
    get: jest.fn(),
  };
  mocked(got).mockResolvedValue(response);

  const result = await anotherGot();
  console.log(result);
  // expect(result).toBe(response.body);
});
```

when I try to run the test (`npm test`)
I got the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

How to handle the code in jest test ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to mock the function `got` itself (which is also a function). But you need to mock `got.get` function.

[Got npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) implemented 2 ways of calling HTTP GET request:

1. `const response = got('http://google.com', { method: 'get' });`
2. `const response = got.get('http://google.com');`

Therefore, if you want to mock your `got.get(...)` you'll need to mock `got.get` and not `got` itself (usecase #2):

```
// api.test.ts
// import { run } from "../api";
import got from "got";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";

jest.mock("got");

test("using another got", async () => {
    const mockedGot = mocked(got);

    // use case #1 - using got module directly
    mockedGot.mockReturnValue({
        json: () => Promise.resolve({ dataAttr1: 'val11111' }),
    } as any)

    const response1 = got('http://www.google.com', { method: 'get' });
    const data1 = await response1.json();
    expect(data1).toEqual({ dataAttr1: 'val11111' })

    /*******************************************************************/

    // use case #2 - using got.get "alias"
    // this is your case :)
    mockedGot.get = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        json: () => Promise.resolve({ dataAttr1: 'val22222' }),
    } as any);

    const response2 = got.get('http://www.google.com');
    const data2 = await response2.json();
    expect(data2).toEqual({ dataAttr1: 'val22222' })
});
```